# Ansible : How to create a task that skips first element of inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

**Example of inventory file**

```
[my-sweet-servers]
server1
server2
server3
```

**Goal:** Execute task on all elements except first (ie. ! [k8-control-plane][0])

**Question:** How do you create a task to skip first element of inventory *(example like below)*

```
- name: Running all actions except first node
  shell: .....
  when: hostvars[item].ansible_host is not hostvars[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `groups` and `inventory_hostname` [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) for this:

```yaml
when: inventory_hostname != groups['k8-control-plane'][0]
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I attempted this once before but must have had a typo. I appreciate the clarification